Drawing arcs with arrowheads
The code below (which uses the pict2e package) seems to do what I intended but I want to do some further editing and add some other lines and label the angles differently.
When angles are adjacent to each other (sharing a common vertex) then explicitness about which pairs of rays emanating from a vertex correspond to which labels giving names of angles can be accomplished by an arc between the two rays and centered at the vertex, with the angle label between the arc and the vertex, and arrowheads at each end of the arc to make clear which two rays bound the arc bearing that label.
Is there any simple way to draw such arcs with arrowheads?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.5mm}
\begin{picture}(200,180)(-35,0)
\label{hexagon}
\put(90,100){\circle{180}}      % left big circle
\put(90,190){\circle*{4}}       % dot at top of circle 
\put(144,172){\circle*{4}}      % dot at
\put(162,46){\circle*{4}}       % dot at
\put(90,10){\circle*{4}}        % dot at bottom of circle
\put(0,100){\circle*{4}}
\put(36,172){\circle*{4}}

\put(90,10){\line(-1,1){90}}    % line
\put(0,100){\line(1,2){36}}
\put(36,172){\line(3,1){54}}
\put(90,190){\line(3,-1){54}}
\put(144,172){\line(1,-7){18}}

\put(90,10){\line(2,1){72}}

\put(0,100){\line(1,1){90}}
\put(0,100){\line(2,1){144}}
\put(0,100){\line(3,-1){162}}

\put(90,10){\line(-1,3){54}}
\put(90,10){\line(0,1){180}}
\put(90,10){\line(1,3){54}}


\put(15,121){$\delta$}
\put(20,115){$\gamma$}
\put(22,100){$\beta$}
\put(18,85){$\alpha$}

\put(103,26){$\beta$}
\put(92,34){$\gamma$}
\put(85,34){$\delta$}
\put(75,30){$\varepsilon$}

\put(36,172){\line(1,0){108}}
\put(36,172){\line(1,-1){126}}
\put(90,190){\line(1,-2){72}}

\put(149,76){$\gamma$}
\put(140,71){$\delta$}
\put(135,59){$\varepsilon$}
\put(137,42){$\zeta$}

\put(113,173){$\delta$}
\put(116,164){$\varepsilon$}
\put(127,152){$\zeta$}
\put(139,146){$\alpha$}


\end{picture}
\caption{}
\label{diagonals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



Please, give a fully compilable code

A question for David, I guess. You could ask him in chat.

@cfr : Who is David?

David Carlisle. Famed for his use of picture.
